# How to determine if a model is empty in Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
@model IEnumerable<Framely2011.Models.Frames>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            PictureID
        </th>
        <th>
            UserID
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.PictureID
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.UserID
        </td>
        <td>
            Meta 1: @item.MetaTagsObj.Meta1 Meta 2: @item.MetaTagsObj.Meta2 Meta 3: @item.MetaTagsObj.Meta3
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

If the model comes up empty, how can I just get it to print "There are no Frames" so that none of the html table gets printed at all, I would think a simple `if` statement would suffice, but I am new to razor and I wasn't sure how I would go about doing this.

Comment: Shouldn't affect anything but I noticed I did not need to add `@using System.Linq` in VS 2013 with MVC 5 but it did still work to use `@if(!Model.Any())`. It wont matter whether you include it or not but I like to use the least amount of lines of code if possible :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add this to the top of the page:

```
@using System.Linq
```

Then replace your code with this block.

```
@if( !Model.Any() )
{
    <tr><td colspan="4">There are no Frames</td></tr>
}
else
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.PictureID
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.UserID
            </td>
            <td>
                Meta 1: @item.MetaTagsObj.Meta1 Meta 2: @item.MetaTagsObj.Meta2 Meta 3: @item.MetaTagsObj.Meta3
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Comment: I add  @using System.Linq to top of razor view page, then added     @if(Model.Any())
                    {
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSuffix, new SelectList(Model.Suffix, "Value", "Text", Model.SuffixDBValue), "") 
                    }      but i get the error 'does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type ..'

Answer (score 0):

You can also just pass the value to the Viewbag form within the controller and check it in the view like below.
1 - The is the controller -

```
int numberOfRecords = db.Jobs.ToList().Count(); - 
ViewBag.numRecords = numberOfRecords;
ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
return View();
```

2 - Then just check in the View

```
@if (ViewBag.numRecords > 0)
```